# Send subscription results back to angular material dialog

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-dialog

So when i trigger an event emitter from the dialog:
...

```
onAdd = new EventEmitter();

onButtonClick() {
  this.onAdd.emit();
}
```

And I listen to this from the parent:

```
let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(Component);
const sub = dialogRef.componentInstance.onAdd.subscribe(() => {
  myservice.subscribe(results => /*send back to dialog*/)
});
```

How can I send "results" back to the same dialog?

Edit: I also need to trigger a function call in the dialog when "results" is ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass value back to your dialog this way:

```
 const sub = dialogRef.componentInstance.onAdd.subscribe(() => {
  myservice.subscribe(results => {
    // passes results to your dialog. you need to create a property 'results' in you dialog class though.
    dialogRef.componentInstance.results = results; 
    dialogRef.componentInstance.someFunction(); // function you want to trigger after results is ready
  })
});
```

Because `dialogRef.componentInstance` gives you the full instance class of the dialog, you can do what you do from the dialog class itself.

Comment: Ah of course! I think this is it. I failed to realize I can also access functions like that. Thanks!